# Umbraco 8 website and Azure CDN (caching for page does not work)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, umbraco, azure-cdn, umbraco8

I am working on a client's website where I need to setup CDN using DNS. I using Azure CDN (Microsoft CDN) and I did it on www prefix, so when you request https://www.taxory.com it is actually loaded from CDN.

It all works fine for images, scripts, and styles. But the actual page does not load from CDN. I can't figure out if that is something related to Umbraco or some configuration in web.config or in Azure CDN.

As you see on the screenshot I have "TCP_HIT" for all my resources and the only one "TCP_MISS" is the actual Umbraco page.

Any idea how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `cache-control` settings of the `www.tasory.com` page. It should not be set to `private` or `nocache`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will look at how to change this in Umbraco.